# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package): By not providing "FindGeant4.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

Tags: software-installation, compiling, cmake

I have a problem trying to install Geant4 on  Linux system.

```
$ cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGeant4.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Geant4", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Geant4" with any
  of the following names:

    Geant4Config.cmake
    geant4-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Geant4" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Geant4_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Geant4"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dell/Desktop/geant4/geant4.9.6/examples/basic/B1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I tried:

```
apt-get install g++
```

But I get:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to source the `geant4.sh`

In the bash shell, give the command:

```
source /path_to_geant4_install/bin/geant4.sh
```

And then do `cmake`

Comment: @Zanna Yes I have used it and it worked. If it doesn't work on your system, do let me know.

Comment: when i tried your command , i am getting no such file or directory.

Comment: I have checked there is no installation dir in my geant4 source dir .

Comment: @WaqasRana Do the following
Run this command in your terminal: locate geant4.sh
And when you get the path, copy paste it in your source command where you want to cmake it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.

It may help to add these commands in `.bashrc`:

```
source /home/user/geant4-install directory/bin/geant4.sh

source /home/user/geant4-install directory/share/geant4-version number/geant4make/geant4make.sh

export G4WORKDIR=/home/user/g4work
```